# How can I apply a watermark in images using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm using angularJS and need to apply a watermark programatelly in images by calling an JS function. What I have is:

```
<figure><img class="watermark" ng-src="{{applyWatermark(img.url)}}"></figure>
```

So, I need to call that function applyWatermark (not implemented yet) and return a img with the watermark, but I'm not sure how can I build this function. Should it return the image? Can someone provide me some example how can I do this?

**EDIT:**

I did this, but it's not working:

```
 $(function applyWatermark(image) {                                                                                                                                                                                                      
     watermark([image, 'watermark.png'])                                                                                                                       
       .image(watermark.image.lowerRight())                                                                                                                                                                                              
       .then(function (img) {                                                                                                                                                                                                            
           return img                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
       });                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 })
```

Any idea?

Comment: Not a good idea. User can always get the origin image from source.

Comment: While this would be useful against some users, watermarking something on the client isn't really a solution as you will have transferred the original to the client before you can actually watermark it with client-side code.

Comment: As **kxxoling** and **Can Ibanoglu** said, it's bad design if you are using it for copyrighting your images. But if it's just to add a caption directly to the image, I guess that's fine. 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [watermark.js](http://brianium.github.io/watermarkjs/):

```
watermark(['/img/forest.jpg', '/img/logo.png'])
    .image(watermark.image.lowerRight(0.5)) // Or lowerRight() for no opacity
    .then(function (img) {
        document.getElementById('alpha-image').appendChild(img);
    });
```

If this doesn't work for you, maybe try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.example.com/your-image.jpg',
    type: 'HEAD',
    error: function() {
        // File isn't found
    },
    success: function() {
        // File is found! Do the watermarkage.
    }
});
```

to test if the image exists before processing.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I tried this way you described, but it's not working, please check my edit in the original post. Have any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: It should definitely work, so long as `image` is the path to an image on the server, and you have correctly referenced the `watermark.js` library.

Comment: I am using this watermark.js. But its create large file after conversion (3 MB to 9 MB). How to reduce file size any idea?

Comment: Here's an idea: first `npm install sharp`, then in your code `const sharp = require('sharp'); sharp(inputBuffer).resize(320, 240).toFile('output.webp', (err, info) => ... );`. Gtihub for the project here: https://github.com/lovell/sharp